# Protractor: browser.actions().mouseMove().click().perform() not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

Im trying to perform a click at an XY location within protractor, however, it is not registering the click within IE. Regular click events on an element work perfectly, but clicking an element using xy coordinates is not registered at all. This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, just not in IE 11. The code I am trying to perform is.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="map"]/div/div[1]')), {
        x: 295
        , y: 225
    }).click().perform();
```